# Single.fromCallable() - Chaining two calls, one after another

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-java2

I'm using `Single.fromCallable()` to make a network call and I want to use the data from the response to make a second call.

How can I chain these two calls instead of nesting them?

```
private void queryForUser() {
    Single.fromCallable(() -> remoteRepository.queryForUser()))
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(response-> {

                    String username = response.getUsername();

                    //Perform second call
                    performSecondQuery(username);

                }, err -> {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Failed to get user", err);
               
                });

}
```

```
private void performSecondQuery(String username){
        Single.fromCallable(() -> remoteRepository.performSecondQuery(username)))
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(secondQueryResult -> {

                    Log.d(TAG, "performSecondQuery: " + secondQueryResult);

                }, err -> {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Failed to perform second query", err);
                });
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `Single#flatMap`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My Java lambda syntax is rusty, but using `flatMap()` should give you something like this:

```java
private Single<Whatever> performSecondQuery(String username){
        return Single.fromCallable(() -> remoteRepository.performSecondQuery(username)))
}

private void queryForUser() {
    Single.fromCallable(() -> remoteRepository.queryForUser()))
                .flatMap { response -> performSecondQuery(response.getUsername()) }
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(
                   // TODO something with the result
                }, err -> {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Failed to get user", err);
                });
}
```

(note: I don't know what the second query is doing, so I don't know what `Whatever` is — it would be the return type of `remoteRepository.performSecondQuery()`)

Comment: How would I reuse the ```response``` value inside the ```.subscribe()```?

Comment: @DIRTYDAVE: I'd rewrite `performSecondQuery()` to take the `response` as a parameter, rather than `response.getUsername()`. Then, have `performSecondQuery()` return a `Single<AnotherWhatever>`, where `AnotherWhatever` is an object that wraps the `response` plus the `Whatever` that it returns now. At that point, your `flatMap()` is converting your original `Single` into a `Single<AnotherWhatever>`, and your `subscribe()` first lambda gets the `AnotherWhatever` with your `response` and your `Whatever` instance.